# add boolean variable to Event Handles

Tags: vb.net

I have two form A and B. When I close A, I need to close B, and viceversa when I close B, I need to close A. Obviously I can't do it, because I call twice the close method at the same form.

I'm thinking to add the variable to  this FormClosed Handles.

```
Public Sub a_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed

End Sub
```

in this way:

```
Public Sub a_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs, flag as Boolean) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
if flag > true
   a.close()
else
  a.close()
  b.close()
end if
End Sub
```

and it doesn't work because it isn't correct.
where i mistake?

Answer (score 2):

The Closing event is more appropriate. "*... as this form is closing, close the other one...*"

Check if an instance of the other form type is open, and close it. Essentially the same code could run for both form's Closing event.

```
Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
        If TypeOf frm Is Form2 Then
            frm.Close()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

(A flag is not necessary.)

---

Note that attempting to `Close` a form in **its** `Closed` event is redundant.

Comment: You can collapse that loop down to a single line if you want: `Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form2)().FirstOrDefault()?.Close()`.